# Simulation in Omnetpp

Tags: omnet++, inet

I used Inet Framework and when I run the simulation it shows the following error.

It says: Error in module (inet::physicallayer::Radio)Inett.hostA.wlan[0].radio (id=34) during network initialization: Module not found on path 'radioMedium' define by par 'Inet.hostA.wlan[0].radio.radioMediumModule'.

Comment: Have you read [MCVE rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Could you provide more information about your simulation (version of INET, version of OMNeT++, which example do you try to run, etc.)?

Comment: I am using Omnet++ 5 and Inet 3.4 And I tried to simulate a example from the tutorial "Two host communicating wirelessly. " (I am new to stackoverflow so I dont have privilege to post photo)

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what the error message says: To model radio communication you need a module named 'radioMedium' at the top level network, which actually simulated the electromagnetic field. I highly suggest to read and follow the Wireless Tutorial: https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/step1.html